# VIM Disable insert mappings of plugins

Tags: vim, mapping

A plugin adds to my insert mappings a mapping for `<leader>is`. I have some ideas which one it can be. But it does not matter I don't want to change anything in foreign plugins. So I want to disable this mapping. I tried this:

```
imap <leader>is  <nop>
```

I did not help.

What is your suggestions?

BTW, I want to ask how disable in vimrc all insert mapping of plugins?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To remove an insert mode mapping, use the `:iunmap` command:

```
:iunmap <Leader>is
```

I don't know whether it is possible to do "bulk unmapping", but at least you can list all active insert mode mappings with

```
:imap
```

or, even better, with

```
:verbose imap
```

which will also tell you where the mapping has been defined in the first place.

---

**Edit:** To clarify, the unmapping needs to be done *after* the plugin has been loaded. To do so, create a file with the following contents in `~/.vim/after/plugin/` (see @ZyX's answer):

```
" myafter.vim: will be executed after plugins have been loaded
iunmap <Leader>is
```

Comment: Vim returns an error: That there is no such mapping. However, this mapping is still in the imap list.

Comment: @user14416 See @ZyX's answer: Putting `:iunmap ...` in your vimrc has no effect! Instead use `:verb imap` to identify the plugin responsible for the mapping, then create an "after" directory for the plugin with your unmapping command.

Comment: I created `after/plugin/<plugin_name>.vim` . Still no effect.

Comment: @user14416 So where *is* the mapping coming from? What plugin is it?

Comment: The plugin location is `plugin/a.vim`. I see that `after/plugin/a.vim` is not even loaded.

Comment: @user14416 Make sure your `after` directory really is in your Vim home directory `$HOME/.vim/` (`:echo $HOME`). I tried it with "a.vim" and it works.

Answer (score 8):

Your command if inserted in the vimrc is executed before plugin defines the intrusive mapping and this is why it has no effect. To make it have effect you should make it run after that plugin which is normally achieved either by putting it into `~/.vim/after/plugin/disable_mappings.vim` (any name instead of `disable_mappings` works). Second is using `VimEnter` event:

```
augroup DisableMappings
    autocmd! VimEnter * :inoremap <leader>ic <Nop>
augroup END
```

. To disable all mappings see `:h 'paste'` and `:h 'pastetoggle'`, also `:h :imapclear` (though the latter will remove mappings instead of temporary disabling them).

---

Of course, you may also use `iunmap` just where I suggested to use `inoremap … <Nop>`. How did I came to forget this command?